# Multi-user MySQL access to return consecutive counter of the new record?

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, concurrency, multi-user

I have written a JSP app where multiple users can login at the same time and all access one table to insert records.

I need to have a running counter of the total records that are being inserted (for all users) which I would like to display on the page before the insert is done (The insert is done when the user presses the Submit button..

So to try to explain in a little more detail; user_a logs in.  On the insert page he gets told he is inserting record 1.  On pressing Submit the record gets inserted.  user_b logs in in and on the insert page he sees that he **will be** inserting record 2 when he Submits a new record into the table counter jumps to 2.

The problem is that I want the counter displayed before the users have done the insert (so I can't return the unique_id).

I know I could fetch the last unique_id before the insert is done, and add 1, however how would I reserve that record knowing that a second user may *at the same time* also want to insert a record (using the method I just described he would get the same unique_id and add 1) - both users ending up with the same number.  Also if the user does not Submit the insert that number must not increment ... so almost a roll-back on the counter type of thing.

**Q:** What strategy could I use, to cater for displaying the total records currently in the table so that the user knows what number of record he is entering?  (I can change the DB if needed.)  I am really looking for ideas of how to achieve this as opposed to just giving me code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a web application and HTTP is stateless, you cannot be sure about the global counter after the HTTP response is sent back to the user. What about changing the type of id? For example as a combination of user and record identifier? This way you'll have to handle only situations, where the same user access the web application from multiple browser at the same time. You will be still able to display the total number of records as well as possible next identifier of the next record. Another option is to use [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), which can be prepared (and remembered) at the time the form is returned to client, but the UUIDs are very hard to remember.

Comment: I also though about doing the insert in two stages ... possibly just adding some data first getting the unique number ... then if the submit is not completed (I.e. the rest of the data is not submitted ... then I roll back the first bit that was inserted ... I may have to use an external counter table for this ... Any thoughts on this kind of approach..?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But you'll have to handle situation, where the user leaves the prepared form (exits between the two phases), because there will be prepared record with correct ID, but no data. This will lead to sparse database and that last identifier will not represent the correct number of inserted records. You can fix this by deleting empty records, but this will break your identifier sequence.

Comment: Hmmmm thank you ... food for thought ... I will definitely have to plan this properly.